# ATtiny402 ADC output is strange

Tags: c, avr, attiny

Implemented a simple ADC program in ATtiny402 using MPLAB X IDE and PICKI4 as the debugger. A potentiometer is connected to the PA2 pin as an input. In the program, the ADC conversion result from the ADC0.RES value is observed **0xFFBC** while the ADC voltage level is the same as the reference level, but the expected is **0x3FF**. For the other voltage levels the ADC0.RES value is also strange (not in the range 0x0 to 0x3FF). But if I right shift the ADC0.RES value to 6 bit the result range becomes 0x0 to 0x3FE which is close to the value referred to in the datasheet (10-bit MAX and MIN value).

So simply I am **shifting 6 bits to the right** of ADC0.RES value to get the ADC result, while I think this should not be required, only ADC0.RES can provide the conversion result.

So, Am I missing something, and why this 6-bit right shift is required?

```
#define F_CPU 20000000UL // CLK frequency is configured to 20 MHz by protected write
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

FUSES = {
    .WDTCFG = 0x00, // WDTCFG {PERIOD=OFF, WINDOW=OFF}
    .BODCFG = 0x00, // BODCFG {SLEEP=DIS, ACTIVE=DIS, SAMPFREQ=1KHz, LVL=BODLEVEL0}
    .OSCCFG = 0x02, // OSCCFG {FREQSEL=20MHZ, OSCLOCK=CLEAR}
    .TCD0CFG = 0x00, // TCD0CFG {CMPA=CLEAR, CMPB=CLEAR, CMPC=CLEAR, CMPD=CLEAR, CMPAEN=CLEAR, CMPBEN=CLEAR, CMPCEN=CLEAR, CMPDEN=CLEAR}
    .SYSCFG0 = 0xC4, // SYSCFG0 {EESAVE=CLEAR, RSTPINCFG=UPDI, CRCSRC=NOCRC}
    .SYSCFG1 = 0x07, // SYSCFG1 {SUT=64MS}
    .APPEND = 0x00, // APPEND {APPEND=User range:  0x0 - 0xFF}
    .BOOTEND = 0x00, // BOOTEND {BOOTEND=User range:  0x0 - 0xFF}
};

LOCKBITS = 0xC5; // {LB=NOLOCK}

volatile uint16_t adcVal = 0 ; 

void clock_conf(){
    _PROTECTED_WRITE(CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB, !CLKCTRL_PEN_bm); // prescaler disabled
    _PROTECTED_WRITE(CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA, CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC20M_gc); //20MHz clock
}

void io_config(){
    PORTA.PIN2CTRL = PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc ; //PA2 digital input buffer and pull-up is disabled
}

void adc_init(){
    ADC0.CTRLA = ADC_FREERUN_bm;                    //Set ADC to free running Mode
    ADC0.CTRLA |= ADC_ENABLE_bm ;                   //enable ADC

    ADC0.CTRLB = ADC_SAMPNUM_ACC64_gc;                //SET the ADC to sum 64 samples
    ADC0.CTRLC |= (1<<ADC_SAMPCAP_bp) | (1<<VREF_ADC0REFSEL0_bp) | (ADC_PRESC_DIV128_gc <<  ADC_PRESC_gp )  ; //reference voltage +5v on VDD and pre-scaler is 128
    ADC0.CTRLD = ADC_INITDLY_DLY256_gc;                //Set the init delay before first sample
    ADC0.MUXPOS = ADC_MUXPOS_AIN2_gc;                //SET PA2 as the input for the ADC
    ADC0.INTCTRL = ADC_RESRDY_bm;                    //enable the result ready interrupt

    ADC0.COMMAND = ADC_STCONV_bm;                    // Start the conversion
}

ISR(ADC0_RESRDY_vect){
    adcVal =  ADC0.RES >> 6 ;  // (ADC0.RES >> 6) returns in range (0x0 to 0x3FE)
}

int main(void) {
    io_config()  ;
    clock_conf() ;
    adc_init()  ;

    sei()  ;
    while (1) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, ADCs usually have the option to return the result left-aligned or right-aligned. You seem to want it right-aligned. Also in case of external ADC, endianess plays a part too.

Comment: Also, in case you read `adcVal` from the calling program while the interrupt is active, you will get race condition bugs since the variable isn't protected.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd expect a rounded value would provide a better result.  `(ADC0.RES + 32) >> 6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
ADC0.CTRLB = ADC_SAMPNUM_ACC64_gc;    //SET the ADC to sum 64 samples
```

So that is why you needed to divide by 64 (right shift by 6 bits).

Comment: Isn't the ISR doing exactly that?

Comment: @SteveFriedl yes, OP's question is "why this 6-bit right shift is required?" Edited the tense.

Comment: I hope leaving ADC0.CTRLB = 0x0 will solve it. BTY it was a silly mistake of mine, I thought it will average 64 samples.